# Creating a Windows XP Professional PE USB ISO on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, iso-image, unetbootin, windows-pe

I am attempting to create a Windows XP PE ISO on Ubuntu 16.04. So far the best way I found was the apparently popular Gandalf PE version that I downloaded and burned to USB.

I am using UNetbootin as software on Ubuntu to burn the ISO file. The ISO I selected was the latest available: http://windowsmatters.com/2016/11/08/gandalfs-win10pe-x86-redstone-build-14393-version-11-07-2016/

But when I insert and boot from USB on the computer that contains Windows XP Professional, it says that there is no boot file on the USB, and starts booting normally.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but does anyone have experience creating a bootable USB ISO with Gandalf on Ubuntu, to boot on a different computer?

What I need is command prompt access, to reset the Windows password.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download `chntpw` from your repo. With access to the physical volume, this will reset/clear your password from a linux environment.

Comment: I am you be more specific for those readers less familiar with Linux than you are